# change name of an attachment to random string

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

When a user of my system enters the name of their attachment I want it to be saved as a random string in my database for security reasons. But I want to display the real name when a user is viewing it. Would need it in ColdFusion or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just asking about how to generate a random string? The quickest way would be to use createUUID(). That makes a longish (35 I think) char random string. You can also use randRand to dynamically pick random letters too.

Comment: aye the user adds the title of the attachment but i want to change it to a random string, but when the user is on viewing the document again they will see the name they input not the random string.

Comment: Ah for that part (they see the original) see Brian's below. :) Thought you had that but just needed the random part.

Comment: I want to add one more important note. You said you wanted a random string for "security reasons." That seems to imply you are storing attachments under web root. Don't. Seriously. It is an incredibly bad idea. Even if you rename the file on upload, a person with a Load Testing tool can execute code in the miliseconds between the upload and the rename. I know because one of my apps got hacked like this. Your uploads should ALWAYS go to a non-web-accessible folder. Period.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you would need to store both the original name of the file and the random string version of the file name in the database. Without storing the original version of the file name, you wouldn't know the original version of the file name. Alternatively, if you have a common naming scheme for your files (that is, all files names as displayed to customers are "nameOfCustomer-coupon.pdf"), the original file name is irrelevant and doesn't need to be stored.

When a request is made for that file, you would use the Content-Disposition HTTP header to display the original file name:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=someFileName.someExtension">
```